# AvroMultipleInputs - Issue adding multiple paths

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, avro

Here is the driver code snippet that i use to add multiple Avro input paths with different mapper classes

```
AvroMultipleInputs.addInputPath(jobConf, new Path(args[0]), IncrementalDataMapper.class, incrSchema);
AvroMultipleInputs.addInputPath(jobConf, new Path(args[1]), BaseDataMapper.class, incrSchema);

AvroJob.setMapOutputSchema(jobConf, Pair.getPairSchema(Schema.create(Type.STRING), incrSchema));

AvroJob.setReducerClass(jobConf, DeltaCaptureReducer.class);
AvroJob.setInputSchema(jobConf, Pair.getPairSchema(Schema.create(Type.STRING), incrSchema));
AvroJob.setOutputSchema(jobConf, incrSchema);
```

When i run this driver, i get the following exception that comes from the method getInputSchemaMap(...) of AvroMultipleInputs

> java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.avro.SchemaParseException:
>   Can't redefine: com.sample.Test

Now what i have done is to simulate the method getInputSchemaMap(...) of AvroMultipleInputs in a standalone program to produce the same issue.

**Standalone code**

*The code that fails,*

```
    Schema.Parser schemaParser = new Schema.Parser();
    String m1 = "path1;" + toBase64("{\"type\":\"record\",\"name\":\"Test\",\"namespace\":\"com.sample\",\"fields\":[ {\"name\":\"BATCH_ID\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"long\"]} ] }");
    String m2 = "path2;" + toBase64("{\"type\":\"record\",\"name\":\"Test\",\"namespace\":\"com.sample\",\"fields\":[ {\"name\":\"BATCH_ID\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"long\"]} ] }");
    String[] schemaMappings = (m1 + "," + m2).split(",");
    for (String schemaMapping : schemaMappings) {
        String[] split = schemaMapping.split(";");
        String schemaString = fromBase64(split[1]);
        System.out.println(schemaString);
        Schema inputSchema;
        try {
            inputSchema = schemaParser.parse(schemaString);
        } catch (SchemaParseException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
```

Now i fixed this by created parser for every mapping as following.

```
for (String schemaMapping : schemaMappings) {
        String[] split = schemaMapping.split(";");
        String schemaString = fromBase64(split[1]);
        System.out.println(schemaString);
        Schema inputSchema;
        try {
            Schema.Parser schemaParser = new Schema.Parser();
            inputSchema = schemaParser.parse(schemaString);
        } catch (SchemaParseException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
}
```

Has anyone tried this? Any ideas to fix?

I also tried to copy the AvroMultipleInputs into my project and change the code to use different parser as described above, but i get the following exception

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
>           at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.lib.MultipleInputs.getInputFormatMap(MultipleInputs.java:93)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.lib.DelegatingInputFormat.getSplits(DelegatingInputFormat.java:55)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.writeOldSplits(JobSubmitter.java:328)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.writeSplits(JobSubmitter.java:320)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.submitJobInternal(JobSubmitter.java:196)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1290)

Answer (score 0):

In fact, i have to customize more files to make it work. I am still not sure about the implications if anything else (I do not know what i don't know)

> AvroMultipleInputs.java
>   DelegatingInputFormat.java
>
> DelegatingMapper.java
>   MapCollector.java
>   TaggedInputSplit.java